# CodeIgniter variables in constructor

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, constructor

I looked up the topics around, but I didn't see something for my case.
So, I have controller filled up with methods, and a construcor which loads the models that i commonly use in this specific controller.
Everything works fine.
I needed to set an array in the constructor like

```
$data["content"]["something"] = "bla bla";
```

Thats all. So I pass the $data["content"] to the view loader, and I'm expecting to have access to

```
$something
```

, but no. It takes it as undefined variable, but why? When I put it in the specific method everything works fine, but when it is in the constructor it says undefined.
Any ideas?
Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access constructor variables in View. You need to pass it to controller's method and pass it to view. For example,

**In Constructor :**

```
$data["content"]["something"] = "bla bla";
```

**In Controller's Method :**

```
$data['something'] = $this->$data["content"]["something"];
```

Now you can pass `$data` to view and access like `echo $something`;

Comment: So. i missed that. but still learning ^^ i hope Paul has something about this.

Comment: Hmm, nope, but thanks. :)
public function __construct(){
parent::__construct();
$section = "bla bla";
}

public function index(){
$data["content"]["section"] = $this->$section;
$this->load->view("view", $data["content"]);
}

Now it says that the variable is empty, strange.

Comment: @PaulReed How you are displaying in View?

Comment: I'm passing on $data["content"], so in the view I access $section.
But the error is here $data["content"]["section"] = $this->$section;
CodeIgniter says that $this->$section is empty property.

Comment: Solved. I made it object. $this->section = "bla bla" and in the controller $data["content"]["section"] = $this->section.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you are not understanding variable scope on this issue. Instead of creatnig a local variable $data try using $this->data which will be available to the entire object (controller)

```
function __construct() {
    ...
    $this->data['content'] = array('test' => 'test');
    ...
}
```

You can then also pass it to the view using the variable $this->data too, and append/modify it at any time during execution.

```
$this->load->view('path/to/view', $this->data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $data["content"]["something"] = "bla bla";
  $this->load->view('path/to/view', $data);
```

Retrieve it like these in view

```
   echo $content["something"];
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to do:

```
$data["content"] = "bla bla";
$data["something"] = "bla bla";

$this->load->view('path/to/view', $data);
```

that way you have all the data strings in your views.

```
<?php echo $something; ?>

<?php echo $content; ?>
```

it's not a good idea to pass 2 variables in one $data string.

Comment: Sure, but I want to pass all the $data["content"] to the view. This is the reason that I use multi-dimentional arrays. In the current case I actually set $data["content"]["section"], $data["content"]["manufacturers"]. So I send $data["content"] the view and I can access $section and $manufacturers.

Comment: i think the best way is to call all the functions a part. and just put $this->load->view('path/to/view', $data); so you jsut have all the data strings in your views.

Comment: The situation is this: I have two almost identical controllers, but I use them with different models, and they use different data. Since they are almost identical I use same views for both controllers, I have some forms in there, and to specify the form url I want to pass a variable which defines it.

Comment: I'm already passing data to the view, this isnt the case. The idea is that I don't want to write $data["content"]["section"] in every method, I just want to set it in the constructor and every method to get it automaticly.

Comment: see the other answer from Edwin. i think that's worth a try.